# Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

I want some clarification regarding some concept in elliptic curves.
In many papers I have seen that, let $E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B $ be an elliptic curve
if $L(E,1) $ (corresponding L-function at s=1) is nonzero and Tate Shafarevich 
group is also nontrivial then MWrank of $E $ is zero. Is it true for all elliptic curves? What is the reason? Is converse also true.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture)

Comment: Yes, it is true for every elliptic curve (over $\mathbb Q$), and it follows from Gross-Zagier and Kolyvagin's work. See here for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124202/deducing-bsd-from-gross-zagier-and-kolyvagin The converse is not known to be true up to now.

Comment: The converse is known to be true under the assumption that the Tate-Shafarevich group is finite. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7294